Unable to run PySpark job using spark operator on kubernetes
I have a minikube cluster installed on my local machine and have installed spark-operator on it. I have also setup the necessary service account and RBAC for it. However when i try to run my Pyspark application as a 'SparkApplication' it is failing with below error.
Error: failed to start container "spark-kubernetes-driver": Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "driver": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown

However, when i try to run it as a Job, it is successful. Which means there is no issue with the app code. Also when i try to run a docker container on the image it also works.
I am not sure what is wrong.
Below is the Dockerfile i am using.
# Use an official OpenJDK runtime as a parent image
FROM openjdk:8-jdk

# Set environment variables
ENV PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3
ENV PYTHON_VERSION=3.8.12
ENV SPARK_VERSION=3.2.0
ENV HADOOP_VERSION=3.2

# Install Python and necessary dependencies
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip && \
    apt-get clean

# Install PySpark
RUN pip3 install pyspark==$SPARK_VERSION

# Set up environment variables for Spark
ENV SPARK_HOME=/spark
ENV PATH=$PATH:$SPARK_HOME/bin
ENV PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python:$PYTHONPATH

# Download and extract Apache Spark
RUN wget -qO- https://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-$SPARK_VERSION/spark-$SPARK_VERSION-bin-hadoop$HADOOP_VERSION.tgz | tar -xvz -C / && \
    mv /spark-$SPARK_VERSION-bin-hadoop$HADOOP_VERSION /spark


# Set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy your application files to the container
COPY . .

RUN mkdir /app/jars

# Set dependencies
RUN wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-azure/3.3.1/hadoop-azure-3.3.1.jar -P /app/jars

RUN chmod 775 ./src/python/spark_app.py

# Define the command to run your application
ENTRYPOINT ["python3","./src/python/spark_app.py"]

Below is the application manifest:
apiVersion: "sparkoperator.k8s.io/v1beta2"
kind: SparkApplication
metadata:
  name: spark-pi
  namespace: spark-apps
spec:
  type: Python
  mode: cluster
  image: "image:tag"
  imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent 
  mainApplicationFile: "local:///app/src/python/spark_app.py"
  sparkVersion: "3.2.0"
  restartPolicy:
    type: Never
  driver:
    cores: 1
    memory: "512m"
    labels:
      version: 3.2.0
    serviceAccount: spark
  executor:
    cores: 1
    instances: 1
    memory: "512m"
    labels:
      version: 3.2.0


have you solved this?

I had similar issue, this was related to version mismatch between the spark-operator install and the spark version in sparkapplication .. pls check and ensure the 2 match
